# How can I get all entries that are equal to, but not after a date?

Tags: templating

Some of the products on my page are time sensitive (events). Currently I am getting them all like this:

```
{% set events = craft.commerce.products.type('event').order('eventStartDate desc') %}
```

I can't use the `expiryDate` as the end date for my event, as I am keeping an archive that I want users to be able to click though. But, I don't want to include these "expired" events in my "upcoming events" list.

I am reading through [this SO thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8992/how-to-show-entries-which-are-live-between-dates-regardless-of-postdate-or-expir) which I think is doing the same thing I am. It's painfully obvious that I don't know what I am doing though.

```
{% set today = now %}
{% set events = craft.commerce.products.type('event').eventEndDate('>= today') %}

: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean
```

`eventEndDate` is a `dateTime` field type.

I am trying (and failing) to get all events that have an end date that is equal to, or before today. Once the event is over `eventEndDate` is after today, I do not want to show it in my list.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only issue is that you're adding "today" to the query as a string, not the variable you've created. try:

```
{% set today = now %}
{% set events = craft.commerce.products.type('event').eventEndDate('>=' ~ today) %}
```

The code in the answer you referred to had the same error, I've fixed it.

Comment: ARGH. Pretty obvious now that you point it out. Thank you so much!